# Assign a Variable to Texbox Control Name

Tags: excel, vba

I am making a program with a lot of Textbox input which will be submitted later, and I would like to assign the Textbox Name as a Variable and use a loop to increment the name of the Text box from Texbox1 to Textbox 20

```
Dim Y As Integer
Dim X As String
Dim I As Integer
For I = 1 To 20
X = "TextBox" & Y
X.Value = ""
Next I
```

Comment: I don't understand what you actually want to do: Please edit your post to clarify if you want to create controls programmatically or rename existing controls or change their contents (textBox values)? What's the practical use of variable `Y` (= 0) within the `For I =1 To 20` loop? What exactly is your issue?

Comment: I have 20 textboxes with names Textbox1 to Textbox20 so rather than writing the textbox names one by one and clearing them I want the name of the control to be a variable so I can use look to increment with for loop to shorten my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like (Me is the name of the UserForm):

```
Dim x As String
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 20
   x = Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).Value
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

Using an online source (https://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/control-loop.htm)

You can loop through them without having to add a variable name:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim cCont As control
For Each cCont In Me.Controls
    cCont.Value = "foo"
Next cCont
End Sub
```

Comment: I would contain within the `For Each...Next` loop: `If TypeOf cCont Is MSForms.TextBox Then ... End If`This way by using this loop your form can have other controls (`CommandButton`, `ComboBox`, `CheckBox` etc.) and won't fail or cause unexpected results as it will only target any `TextBox`.